# Nested controller design: What is the correct way to convert PHP structure to ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently am in the process of starting to convert an old internal PHP website to a RoR website. The website serves as a vital application for many departments: Billing, Communications, Technical, etc.

The typical URL looks like this: www.website.com/modules/#{department}/#{department specific task}/#{department specific action}

For example: http://www.website.com/modules/communications/inventory/createitem.php

In RoR, I am trying to grasp if "modules", "communications", and "inventory" should have controllers. The "modules" controller would do some logic and then forward to the communications controller and so on. Is this the correct way?

Comment: As the question is now, it can not really be answered. It looks like you have have not the right understanding what controllers are. What you want is probably what we call "nested resources".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want a controller for each entity that you can interact with in any way.  For example.  If you want your admin to be able to create new modules, then you'll want a modules controller.  Otherwise you just need a modules route (config/routes.rb)

Assuming each of your departments are static, then most likely just namespace modules and each department name.  In this case `Inventory Item` would be a model, you would nest inventory inside of of the communications namespace.  And because Rails is RESTful by nature then your routes for that example above my be:

```
namespace: "modules" do
  namespace: "commnications" do
    namespace: "inventory" do
      resources: inventory_items
    end
  end
end
```

From that, you'll only have 1 controller, inventory_items_controller.rb

So for the url:

- GET -- /modules/communications/inventory/inventory_items/1

  - Will display the details of inventory item 1
- GET -- /modules/communications/inventory/inventory_items

  - Will display the details a list of all inventory items
- POST -- /modules/communications/inventory/inventory_items

  - Will trigger the create action

... etc

Note that this will only work if the model inventory is not needed in any other department.  but you didn't provide that level of detail :)

-- As far as redirecting to other controllers, yes, any controller can call a redirect - but I kind of doubt that's what you want to do.  If a user wants to create a new inventory item in communications, wouldn't they just click on a link to go directly to that page?  If that's not the case, What kind of business logic do have in mind that would need to do the redirecting?

Comment: "What kind of business logic do have in mind that would need to do the redirecting?" Nothing specific, I was just trying to understand the route to take. hank you for the information!